# C# Naming Convention (Title vs. Name)

Tags: c#, naming-conventions

I have a series of classes that implement a Title (or Name) depending upon which word you semantically choose.  Is there a C# naming convention standard for Title vs Name?

Comment: **Always** use `Title` or `Id`, *never* `Name`. Does that make sense? If not, the question is probably subjective `:)`

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Both are pretty common.

In my observation, `Name` is used more frequently for an object with an internal name or for business objects that naturally has a Name property (such as a person).  For examples consider `MemberInfo.Name` and `IIdentity.Name`.  Files are generally considered to have a "filename", and Names often serve the purpose of being at least a part of the object's identity.

Title is used more often to refer to a User Interface Control object or a business object that naturally has a title, like an article.

Personally, I think of a Title as being something that is human-readable, where as a Name is more of a locally scoped identifier that may or may not be human-readable.  (I don't mean that the name has to be completely unique, but in many cases, it is - Either way, it tends to provide some identification in its use-context).  I conceptually think of "Title" as closer to being interchangeable with "Label" than it is with "Name".

Answer (score 8):

This may not be a C# question but a common sense question applicable to many other areas beyond computers:

```
class Author
{
  string Name{..};
}

class Book
{
  string Title{..};
}
```